# R: replacing NA values between two specific values by row

Tags: r

I am trying to get my data ready for a later sequence analysis; to do this I need to insert the value 1 between the values 1 and 2.
So all the NA's between the values of 1 and 2 become equal to 1 for each row. I've included an example table below; in my actual data each row is a unique individual and each column is a time period. The 1 represents admission, the 2 discharge from a program. I am attempting to get the periods between 'admission' and 'discharge' to equal 1 to signify being enrolled in the program and then setting the remaining NA's to 0 to signify not being in a program. There can be multiple admissions per row/individual.

I've been trying to use apply, with which I can change the values themselves, however I can't replace the NA's between the values 1 and 2. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
mdat <- matrix(c(1,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,1,NA,2,  NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,2), nrow = 2, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE,
           dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.4", "C.5", "C.6", "C.7", "C.8", "C.9", "C.10")))
```

```
|      | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8| c9 | c10 |
----------------------------------------------------------
|row 1 | 1  | NA | NA | NA | 2  | NA | NA | 1 | NA | 2   |
|row 2 | NA | NA | 1  | 2  | NA | NA | NA | 1 | NA | 2   |
```

the desired result;

```
|      | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8| c9 | c10 |
----------------------------------------------------------
|row 1 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | NA | NA | 1 | 1  | 2   |
|row 2 | NA | NA | 1  | 2  | NA | NA | NA | 1 | 1  | 2   |
```

Comment: How large is your real-life dataset? (ie, is performance an issue?)

Comment: Sorry should have stated that in the question, the real life data set is quite large, 1700 rows/individuals with approx 4000 columns/time periods

Comment: hi, concerning you desired output, it doesn't match what said in the Q *"setting the remaining NA's to 0"*. Do you still need this ?

Comment: You only have 1s and 2s, no other integer?

Comment: This would have been a lot easier if your data-collection code assigned a "3" to patients currently admitted and a "4" to patients discharged, for example.  While there are good solutions to your specific problem here, the real solution is to fix the code that generates your data set in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** We can get a relatively compact solution by using `na.locf` from the zoo package to fill in the NAs and then replacing elements of `mdat` corresponding to 1s in the filled in version with 1:

```
library(zoo)

replace(mdat, t(na.locf(t(mdat))) == 1, 1)
```

giving:

```
     C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 C.5 C.6 C.7 C.8 C.9 C.10
row1   1   1   1   1   2  NA  NA   1   1    2
row2  NA  NA   1   2  NA  NA  NA   1   1    2
```

**2)** Alternately use `na.locf` and replace any propagated 2s which are NA in `mdat` with NA.  We use a dplyr pipeline (although this could be eliminated if desired):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mdat %>% t %>% na.locf %>% t %>% replace(. == 2 & is.na(mdat), NA)
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you need, you can first replace the `NA` by `0`, then search for occurrences of 2 compare to 1, on a byrow basis, to fill the "gaps" with `1` (the result is then transposed in order to keep the former format):

```
mdat[is.na(mdat)] <- 0
mdat <- t(apply(mdat, 1, function(x) {x[cumsum(x==2) < cumsum(x==1)] <- 1; x}))
mdat
#     C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 C.5 C.6 C.7 C.8 C.9 C.10
#row1   1   1   1   1   2   0   0   1   1    2
#row2   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   1   1    2
```

Comment: There are `zoo` functions which do all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: completely different answer.  I'm not completely clear on what the OP wants, but this code, albeit slowly, will replace all `NA` immediately following a `1` with `1` .  I'm posting just so that anyone with free time and a copy of `microbenchmark` can see how much better `na.locf` does.

```
foo <- c(1,NA,2,NA,1,2,1,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA)
foo
length(foo)
for(jj in 2:length(foo) ) {
if ( (!is.na(foo[jj-1]) && foo[jj-1]==1) & is.na(foo[jj])) foo[jj]=1
}
foo
#then replace remaining `NA` with zero if desired
```

Comment: Hey Carl, you've mentioned that you need to use `zoo` and `na.fill`. But you did not mention the way to use it. Do add the code required to (which I think is pretty simple), else it would be a half answer. Regards.

Comment: @BhargavRao  I intend to -- but don't have an `R` installation at work, and I never post code until I test it --  so it will be a while before I post a working example.

Comment: Not at all a problem. Check out [R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/) if possible. The sooner you edit the better.

Comment: Naaah. just go with G. Grothendieck's `zoo` answer.

Comment: Do I smell a deletion in Progress :/

Comment: @BhargavRao  yes you do; but first many thanks for pointing me to r-fiddle.